# Influence Elasticsearch result scores by user-specific counters

Tags: elasticsearch

I am working on a search solution based on Elasticsearch. I am not an expert when it comes to Elasticsearch and try to wrap my head around the scoring possibilities when it comes to user-specific rankings in a multi-user system.

The scenario is as follows: I have a type called company which is indexed in Elasticsearch:

```
{
    "id": "GUID"
    "name": "string",
    "type": "string",
    // ... and more
}
```

What I want to achieve is to setup user-specific stats that keep track of things like:

- How often was a certain company opened?
- When was it last opened?

... and use those stats in order to influence the search scores of the results.

Elasticsearch seems to have plenty of options to manipulate the scores but so far I wasn't able to get a solution that does what I want. Every example I find only uses values on the document itself, though I don't want to keep track of user activity on nested documents on every searchable entry.
Anyone any ideas on how to achieve what I need? Is it even possible to do with Elasticsearch?